# Can not check the JSON value from the response body

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I just started testing the api using the postman. I have come across one problem with the json path..

in json file I have code which looks like this

```
{
 "users": [
   {
     "firstName": "UserOne",
     "lastName": "One",
     "subjectId": 1,
     "id": 1
   },
   {
     "firstName": "UserTwo",
     "lastName": "Two",
     "subjectId": 2,
     "id": 2
   },
   {
     "firstName": "UserThree",
     "lastName": "Three",
     "subjectId": 3,
     "id": 3
   }
 ],
 "subjects": [
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "SubOne"
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "SubTwo"
   },
   {
     "id": 3,
     "name": "SubThree"
   }
 ]
}
```

I start the json server with `json-server --watch db.json`

After that I send GET request using postman
Request URL `http://localhost:3000/users`

this is the body I get

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "UserOne",
        "lastName": "One",
        "subjectId": 1,
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "firstName": "UserTwo",
        "lastName": "Two",
        "subjectId": 2,
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "firstName": "UserThree",
        "lastName": "Three",
        "subjectId": 3,
        "id": 3
    }
]
```

I was trying to verify the firstName from the id 1 using the snippet code below

```
pm.test("Your test name", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.users[0].firstName).to.eql('UserOne');
});
```

But the output was
`FAIL Your test name | TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

I need help here because the json path `users[0].firstName` should give me the first index..

Comment: Have you tried logging jsonData to see if the users array exists in your response?

Comment: yes `var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(jsonData.users);
`     output `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no key `users` in your response, so when you try to access the non-existed key, you will get error `Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined`. To fix that, you just need:

```
pm.test("Your test name", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData[0].firstName).to.eql('UserOne');
});
```